# SAP Crystal Report-invalid PATH IE 10

Tags: crystal-reports, internet-explorer-10

Im using IE 10 to access the folder of the Crystal report from the Server, when I try to view the report this Message shows:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Invalid path /CrystalReports/view was requested

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message Invalid path /CrystalReports/view was requested

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Invalid path /CrystalReports/view was requested).


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/5.5.20
```

But when I'm using a different browser(Chrome or Firefox) it loads the Report successfully.
The end-users can't use other browsers because of restrictions and security policies enforced by the company.

Answer (score 0):

Open internet explorer 10.
press alt and select tools > f12 developer tools.
change the browser mode to internet explorer 7.
check the report is loading or not.